# Fibers of a principal $G$- bundle are diffeomorphic to $G$.

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-writing, differential-topology, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

> **Definition:** A principal bundle $\pi:P \rightarrow M$ with structure group $G$ is a fiber bundle $P$ with a right action of the Lie group $G$ on the fibers, such that
> $$\pi(pg)= \pi(p), \quad p \in P , g \in G, $$
> and such that the action of $G$ is free and transitive on the fibers.

**Context:** I want to prove the following statement:

> The fibers of the bundle $P$ are diffeomorphic to $G$ itself.

**What I've done so far:** To show it, I've fixed a fiber $P_m:=\pi^{-1}(m)$, $ m \in M$ and chosen an element $p $ in this fiber, and then considered the map
$$f_p : G \rightarrow P_m$$
given by $f_p(g)= pg$ for $g\in G$.

Using the fact that the action of $G$ on $P_m$ is free and transitive, I've proven that $f_p$ is bijective.

**Question:** How does one show that this map $f_p$ is differentiable?

Any help please!

Comment: What is your definition of fiber bundle?

Comment: It's the following:   Definition: let $\pi: \mathcal{E} \rightarrow M $ be a smooth map from a manifold $\mathcal{E}$ to a manifold $M$. We say that $(\mathcal{E},\pi)$ is a fiber bundle with typical fiber $E$ over$M$ if there is a covering of $M$ by open sets $U_i$ and diffeomorphisms $\phi_i : \pi^{-1} (U_i) \rightarrow U_i \times E,$ such that $\pi: \pi^{-1}(U_i) \rightarrow U_i$ is the decomposition of $\phi_i$ with projection onto the first factor $U_i$ in $U_i \times E$.

Comment: Pick an open set $U\subset M$ and a smooth section $\sigma:U\rightarrow \pi^{-1}(U)$. Try to prove that the map $U\times G\rightarrow \pi^{-1}(U)$, $(p,g)\mapsto \sigma(p)g$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: You better require that the action of the Lie group on the principal bundle is a smooth action.

Comment: My bad, a bad habit of mine is if I talk about Lie groups I automatically assume that everything is smooth. :)

Comment: Oops,  didn't think about this, Thanks @Thorgott for your comment!

Comment: @Laci, thank you. I'm thinking about your comment , but I'm not sure how can one ensure the existence of the smooth section $\sigma: U \rightarrow  \pi^{-1}(U) ?$

Comment: As you said, you have an open cover of M $\{U_i\}$ and for each $U_i$ there exists a diffeomorphism $\psi_i:\pi^{-1}(U_i)\rightarrow U_i\times E$ such that $\pi=\text{pr}_1 \circ \psi_i$. Over $U_i$ let $\sigma_i(p)=\psi^{-1}_i(p,e)$, where $e\in E$. This will be a smooth section over $U_i$.

Comment: Oki , gracias :)